# Is it ok to proxy the Keycloak APIs

Tags: keycloak, http-proxy

Our website needs to have popup models for login and register and as I know Keycloak requires us to open a new tab for user to get logged in, so the solution came to my mind was to proxy the apis to have our custom login - register scenario, Is it technically ok? or is there any better solution?

I tried proxing the Keycloak apis